# Add button over image and Send image to server. After getting image from server show the button on exact same place

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I am bit confused to make screen over ios and getting challenge to do the task. I have a image that is either clicked by camera or taken from library. After getting it from library/camera user will show some tag over the picture. Let say i have a girl picture who wear a shoes , skirt, top and a necklace. When user wants to post this picture to server these tag/button will be bounded to image and this image send to server. When user come to feed on which that image is being displayed all the button user created is getting on the image. So after getting image from server how i will identify the place in picture where i have to show the button so that other user can tap over them and get the details of the product. This is how i need in the app. See the picture below.[image: Look out the bluish button there i need like this]

This is exactly happening over POSE iphone app. Here is the link of that app try to make some outfit there and see what happening. 
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pose/id402272154?mt=8

I need to implement this kind of functionality i have some ways in mind but better before working over them i thought take some genuine advise from the people.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to send cordinates also to server and fetch them too for other users

Comment: Yes abhishek i thought this but server is keeping the image on some specific size and when it is being displayed to user that is a fix size image view in that case might be button can get distorted i thought that idea but do you have any other option to make it i mean each ios family produce various kind of size of images for user. how we will going to manage them.

Comment: ok no problem then simply you can get cordinates by getting scaleFactor in between original image size and imageview size


suppose that your cordinates are 10,10
imageview size is 100,100
and origianal image size is 200,200

its means simply scalefactor  is 2,2

simply multiply your cordinates by scale factor